# Не работает автокомплит для поля «Откуда» в профиле

Tags: дефект, поддержка, профиль-участника

Раньше при заполнении в профиле поля «Откуда» после введения нескольких букв появлялся выпадающий список с возможными вариантами, сейчас же, при заполнении этого поля под ним появляется надпись «Мы не узнаем это местоположение – попробовать ещё раз?».

Что-то поменяли и это нормально? Или что-то сломалось?

PS. Проявляется на ru.SO и meta.ru.SO, на en.SO работает как и раньше.

Comment: Работает как-то странно, только с теми значениями, которые вводил на enSO. Т.е. открываем например в двух вкладках. Вводим на enSO, а потом видим, что оно начинает работать для этих же строк на ruSO. Ну и там надпись ещё "Powered by Google", может как-то настроено иначе для ruSO. Я когда туда вносил координаты, вообще не помню, чтобы там был что-то гуглоподобное. Может быть раньше это было обычное поле ввода.

Comment: @alexolut, Когда я вводил информацию в это поле, автокомплит был.

Comment: Сегодня смог исправить местоположение только через сохранение из enSO на все сообщества. Из ruSO функция не работала вообще.